# Fibres of a morphism and residue field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If I have a morphism of schemes $f: X \rightarrow S$ and a point $s$ in $S$, then I can consider the fibre $X_s$ over that point.

If $x$ is a point in $X$ which is also (topologically) in $X_s$, is then the residue field of $x$ as point in $X$ and as point in $X_s$ the same?

Of course, I tried to solve it locally, but was confused by the many localizations and possible isos.
Perhaps you can give a hint if the statement is true and a short note how to show it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's better if you try to solve the exercise by yourself. Think about the universal property of fiber product and the following (if you don't already know this beware: this is EXTREMELY important to understand scheme theory). If $X$ is any scheme and $k$ any field, what you need to specify if order to define a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(k) \to X$?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Ricky; with your hint it is indeed very easy. One defines a morphism $Spec(k(x)) \rightarrow X_s$ by universal property, as one has naturally a morphism into $X$ and into Spec(k(s)). The commutativity of the received diagram shows that one has two inclusions of the residue fields in question which composed are the identity. So you can conclude.

Comment: You may want to think through the local argument again, since it shouldn't be that confusing.  In local terms, you are asking:
if $(A,\mathfrak m) \to (B,\mathfrak n)$ is a local morphism of local rings, then does the natural map from $B \to B/\mathfrak m B$ induce an isomorphism of residue fields?